Unable to delete collection from the firestore console
Does anyone face the same issue where some of the root collections in the Firestore console cannot be deleted even after typing the exact ID?

This is how it looks like when I type in the exact ID. Does anyone have solutions/suggestions for this? Thank you!!

Most likely, you have a white space after the collection name. So to be able to delete the collection, you have to type "Users " instead of "Users". See the white space after the collection name?

Okay yea youre right there was a whitespace i missed out. Thank you!
